# Reading a specific line with f.readline() - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, readline

```
async def token():
  global counterA
  global counterB
  
  counterA = 0
  counterB = 0
  
  
  while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    counterA += 1
    counterB += 2
    
    with open('counter.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write (str(counterA))
        f.write ("\n")
        f.write (str(counterB))
        f.write ("\n")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global counterA
    global counterB

    with open('counter.txt', 'r') as f:
      counterA = int(f.readline())
    with open('counter.txt', 'r') as f:
      counterB = int(f.readline())

    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(token())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Im trying to read the second line (counterB) when I turned the bot on, so the counter doesn't restart

Instead of getting the second line (counterB) value, I got the first line value(counterA) when i run the bot

So, Im trying to get a specific / certain line from counter.txt

Comment: When you open file it will always start from first, so you have to call readLine() second time, in first With close only, Instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readline()` reads a file line by line.

If you need a random line info from a file, you can use the `readlines()` method which returns the lines as a list and then you can use the index based access to directly get a particular line info.

For example, to get `second` line value, use the following:

```
with open('counter.txt', 'r') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
      secondLine = lines[1]
```

Comment: Please note that that means you will need to take the entire file into memory which may be quite memory intensive depending on your filesize.

Comment: @BryanFBT the question is not if it works or not but rather that you should be aware of any inefficiencies built into functions you are using.

Answer (score 2):

`f.readlines()` returns a list of lines, e.g my txt file looks like this:

```
Hello world!
This is something
I'm writing
```

The return result of `f.readlines` would be:

```py
result = ["Hello World!\n", "This is something\n", "I'm writing\n"]
```

Let's say I want the second line:

```py
>>> line = 2
>>> result[line - 1] # Remember, indexes start at 0
"This is something\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one line,then instead of reading all lines,read untill you get N th line,

```
s=''
for i in range(n) :
  s=f.readline()
```